# Directshow.NET and system instability

Tags: windows-7, directshow, directshow.net

I have an application running on Windows 7 which is basically a video player based on DirectShow.NET. In order to play videos one after the other with a seamless transition I am preloading the next video (by calling mediacontrol.pause()) while playing the 'current' one. Normally this works absolutely fine, however in some cases the pause never completes and just hangs. I have been over the code many times and can find no evidence of memory leaks or anything like that.

Now, the really interesting thing is that it works fine in my office but not in another. I can take a working pc to the remote office and have it break on a fairly regular basis, but I then bring it back here and it works flawlessly. This leads me to believe that something in the building is causing the system instability. Would possible causes could there be and how could I test for this?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition.  You may never find it, if it's inside DirectShow.  There's no hope of us finding it, given the dearth of information you've provided.

Comment: DirectShow has not aged well, it is considerably past its expiration date.  Pretty visible in DirectShow.NET, a lot of its sample programs don't work correctly anymore.  Media Foundation is the way forward.

Comment: If it was a race condition, why would it happen every 30 - 60 minutes at one location, and not once in weeks of testing at another? As I said, it isn't even two different PCs, I physically took it from one location to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be told from this information except that you need to proceed with the investigation. If you have a freeze, you can take a snapshot of the frozen process and narrow down the scope of the deadlock.

There is nothing in DirectShow core and stock filters to cause the mentioned effect, or at the very least it is highly unlikely. Typical cause would be that one of the third party filters participating in the playback graph is behaving itself incorrectly. Or, next likely cause is that video adapter driver is exhibiting issues when you are playing too many files at a time, esp. if specific features such as hardware accelerated decoding are being used.

Freezing call stack and exact filter graph topology is what you need to move on with the troubleshooting.